# The path of Video is set and get through realm but the video is not displayed in Listview

Tags: android, android-videoview

**My Activity**

```
public class CommonChattingAttachmentActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_chatting_attachment);

        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        commonchat = findViewById(R.id.commonchat);
        functions = findViewById(R.id.functions);
        //times=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.times);

        imglocation=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglocation);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                CommonChat items = (CommonChat) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e5e5e5"));
                change2();

            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                CommonChat item = (CommonChat) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a9a9a9"));
                change1();
                h=item.getDescription();
                onclick();
               // onitemclick();
                return true;

            }
        });

         imgcopy = (ImageView) functions.findViewById(R.id.imagecopy);
         imgdelete=(ImageView) functions.findViewById(R.id.imgdelete);


        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setAdapter();
        displayInputDialog();
       //    timed();
        imgcam=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgcam);
        imgallery=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imggallery);
        imgattach=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgattach);
        imgallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                galleryIntent();
            }
        });
        imgcam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraIntent();
            }
        });
        imgattach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        imglocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


  Intent i = new Intent(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });



    }

public void onclick()
{
    imgcopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            cm.setText(h);
        }
    });
    imgdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String type = h;
            final RealmResults<CommonChat> students = realm.where(CommonChat.class).findAll();

            CommonChat CommonChat = students.where().equalTo("description", type).findFirst();

            if (CommonChat != null) {

                if (!realm.isInTransaction()) {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                }

                CommonChat.removeFromRealm();

                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
        }
            //final int position2 = holder.getAdapterPosition();



    });

}
    public void setAdapter()
    {
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        final CommonChatRealmHelper helper=new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        helper.retrieveFromDB();
        CCAA adapter=new CCAA(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        realmChangeListener=new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                CCAA adapter=new CCAA(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,helper.justRefresh());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    //DISPLAY INPUT DIALOG
    public void displayInputDialog()
    {

        //EDITTEXTS
        descEditTxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editwrite);
        ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send);

        //SAVE
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String desc = descEditTxt.getText().toString();
                CommonChat s = new CommonChat();
                s.setDescription(desc);
                CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
                if (helper.save(s)) {
                    descEditTxt.setText("");
                    setAdapter();
                   // addImages();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }




        });
    }

    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        //intent.putExtra("camera",REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }
    public void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
    }
    public void SaveMapData(String result1,String result2) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            s.setLatitude(result1);
            s.setLongitude(result2);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
            if (helper.save(s)) {
                setAdapter();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           // Log.d("path", result);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Set Image URL"+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nope its not done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library","Camera Video","Gallery Video","Current Location",
                "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("Camera Video")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Camera Video";
                    if(result)
                        startRecording();
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("Gallery Video")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Gallery Video";
                    if(result)
                        CaptureVideoFromGallery();
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("Current Location")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Current Location";
                    if(result)
                      mapactivity();
                }

                    else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
public void mapactivity()
{




 Intent i=new Intent(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
    public void startRecording()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        // create a file to save the video
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set the image file name
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // set the video image quality to high
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        // start the Video Capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    }
    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){

        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        // Check that the <a href="#">SDCard</a> is mounted
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraVideo");


        // Create the storage directory(MyCameraVideo) if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){

            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){

               // output.setText("Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");

               // Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("MyCameraVideo", "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");
                return null;
            }
        }



        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(date.getTime());

        File mediaFile;

        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {

            // For unique video file name appending current timeStamp with file name
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public void CaptureVideoFromGallery()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), SELECT_FILES);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            }
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
           else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILES) {
                onSelectFromGalleryVideoResults(data);
            }
            else if(requestCode==1)
            {
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    String result1=data.getStringExtra("lat");
                    String result2=data.getStringExtra("lng");

                        SaveMapData(result1,result2);


                }

            }
            else if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURE) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video has been saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SaveVideoData(String.valueOf(data.getData()));
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"My bm"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(data.getData()),"gallery");

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryVideoResults(Intent data) {

        Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"My bm"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SaveVideoData(String.valueOf(data));

    }

    public void  onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"No Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"Error Arrived",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"Error Arrived again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(destination),"camera");
        Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"its done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    public void SaveImageVideoData(String data,String flag) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            s.setImageUrl(data);
           // s.setVideoUrl(data);
            s.setFlag(flag);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
            if (helper.save(s)) {
                setAdapter();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Set Image URL"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nope its not done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public void SaveVideoData(String data) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
           // s.setImageUrl(data);
            s.setVideoUrl(data);
            //s.setFlag(flag);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
            if (helper.save(s)) {
                setAdapter();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Set Image URL"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nope its not done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    public void change1()
    {
        commonchat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        functions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    public void change2()
    {
        commonchat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        functions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();}
}
```

**My Adapter Class**

```
public class CCAA extends ArrayAdapter<CommonChat> {


    public CCAA(Context context, List<CommonChat> objects){
        super(context,0,objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        contactList = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public CommonChat getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final CCAA.ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_commonchat, parent, false);
            vh = CCAA.ViewHolder.create((LinearLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (CCAA.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        CommonChat s = getItem(position);

        if(s.getVideoUrl()!=null && s.getVideoUrl().length()>0)
        {
            vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vh.videoView.setVideoPath(s.getVideoUrl());
            vh.videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(context));
            vh.videoView.start();
            Log.d("start error testing", "test");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Got Video URL" + s.getVideoUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


        if(vh.txtbeencnt!=null) {
            vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vh.txtbeencnt.setText(s.getDescription());
        }



        if(s.getImageUrl() != null && s.getImageUrl().length()>0) {

            if (s.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("gallery")) {
                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Got Gallery Image URL" + s.getImageUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (s.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("camera")) {

                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s.getImageUrl());
                vh.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Got Camera Image URL" + s.getImageUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


        return vh.rootView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final LinearLayout rootView;
        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final TextView txtbeencnt;
        public final VideoView videoView;
        public final TextView times;

        private ViewHolder(LinearLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView txtbeencnt, VideoView videoView,RelativeTimeTextView times) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.txtbeencnt = txtbeencnt;
            this.videoView = videoView;
            this.times = times;


        }

        public static CCAA.ViewHolder create(LinearLayout rootView) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            VideoView videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            TextView txtbeencnt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textdesc);
            RelativeTimeTextView times = (RelativeTimeTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.times);
            times.setReferenceTime(new Date().getTime());
            return new CCAA.ViewHolder(rootView, imageView, txtbeencnt, videoView,times);
        }

    }
}
```

**My Logcat**

```
Unexpected activity pause without a matching activity resume. Logging data may be incorrect. Make sure you call activateApp from your Application's onCreate method
10-31 11:10:42.157 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-31 11:10:55.247 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:10:55.257 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:10:55.257 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:10:55.257 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/path: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4
10-31 11:10:55.257 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/working realm: yes....
10-31 11:10:55.367 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/start error testing: test
10-31 11:11:03.157 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-31 11:11:05.147 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.147 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:146337 flg=0x1 }},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.157 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.157 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:146337 flg=0x1 }},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.157 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.157 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:146337 flg=0x1 }},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.167 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.167 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:146337 flg=0x1 }},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.167 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/VID_20171031_111040.mp4},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.167 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:null},{videoUrl:Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:146337 flg=0x1 }},{MediaPathType:null},{flag:null},{date:null},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null}]
10-31 11:11:05.167 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/path: Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:146337 flg=0x1 }
10-31 11:11:05.167 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/working realm: yes....
10-31 11:11:05.217 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/start error testing: test
10-31 11:11:05.237 29588-29588/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/start error testing: test
```

Can Anyone Please tell me where I am wrong because i am getting the path of video from camera as well as from gallery but the problem is that the video is not shown in listview as it returns blank.Please Look at my edited and full Logcat to get more idea about the error.

Comment: you want to play it in the list or just want to show the thumbnail in the list?

Comment: I want the video to be played in my listview

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the path in post {videoUrl:file:///storage/emulated/0/1509080683539.mp4} is not correct

```
if(s.getVideoUrl()!=null && s.getVideoUrl().length()>0){
      vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      File videoFile = new File(s.getVideoUrl);
      vh.videoView.setVideoPath(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
      vh.videoView.start();
      vh.videoView.setMediaController(newMediaController(context));
      Toast.makeText(context, "Got Video URL" + s.getVideoUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**PostText**: Don't ever forget to add permission `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` when reading a file.

Comment: if it also doesn't help then let me know, and in case of work done, you may mark the question as done and plus vote will keep us motivated for helping you. :)

Comment: No Sir, it didn't  worked for me. But thanks for your reply! I already added this code the way you said but it didn't work...

Comment: do you see any exception or any other log in logcat? if you post that can be a lead.

Comment: I just edited the answer, you may try now. But untill and unless you post thel logcat the exact problem ca't be sort out. do it in a sample project and send to me i will make it play and then will send you back the code and will let you know what was the problem actually.

Comment: http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4                                                              add this string to setVideoPath(); if this video plays then you definetly have issue with the path.

Comment: I added the specified string by you in the setVideoPath() but the video was not able to play. And please go through my edited and full logcat.